# Angular UI select2 with tags not working inside custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, jquery-select2

Using the Angular UI Select2 directive, with tags defined on an input field. If the input is itself inside a custom directive, then it is not initialised correctly and the console gives an error:

`query function not defined for Select2 tagging`

I suspect this might be to do with the order in which the directives are compiled / linked vs when the select 2 function is called.

Maybe there is a simple workaround, perhaps using the compile function or a directive controller instead of a link function?  Or maybe it is an issue with the Angular UI select2 directive.

I have made a plunker that displays the problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/myE5wZ

So my question is - How do you get get select2 tags working from inside a custom Angular directive?

Comment: Found a workaround:

If you define the variables on the controller scope, and then pass them into the directive it works.

http://plnkr.co/edit/oHAWrK .

So I think this is to do with when things are available on the scope, the link function is clearly not the right the place to do this.  I would ideally still like a solution where I could encapsulate the select2 options inside the scope, instead of having to define everything in the parent controller if anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end I managed to find a solution I was happy with involving nesting two directives, that way the logic can be encapsulated inside the parent directive (not spilling out into the controller).

A Plunker of my solution is here for anyone who may stumble across the same issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZxAPF5BzkgPtn9xddCRM

Comment: This is great. It's the one solution I've found that has gotten me as close to what I need to do working but I'm still stuck. I'm trying to pre-select the objects that are output in the console, but the query function isn't getting called http://plnkr.co/edit/0UVGid?p=preview. Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

I just encountered this today and summarily realized the fix:

PostLinking functions are executed in reverse order (deepest grandchild to greatest grandparent).

Put your custom modal's code (or anything that sets $scope data for use in its children) inside a *PreLinking* function. *PreLinking* functions go from parent to child, and all PreLinking functions are performed before the PostLinking functions.

Comment: Hint for beginners: You need to define the compile-function of the definition object like in `compile: function(element, attributes){
         return {
             pre: function(scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn){
 scope.select2Option = { query: function(options){}
             },
             post: function(scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn){
 
             }
         }
     },
`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Your solution works but IMHO I think an even better solution is to use the controller function instead of the link function inside the directive. Doing this you do need nested directives.

Comment: I ended up writing my own directive and leaving angular ui to its own devices.  I'd be interested to see the controller function implementation if you have time to create a plnkr.

Answer (score 0):

By using the controller function instead of the link function in the directive it's working. Example:

```
function myFunction() { 
  var dir = {};
  dir.scope = { myModel: '=' };
  dir.restrict = 'E';
  dir.templateUrl = 'myTemplate.html';
  dir.replace = true;
  dir.controller = function ($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = ...;
  };

  return dir;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this error too. My short solution:

```
<input type="hidden" 
       name="citizenship" 
       class="form-control input-sm col-sm-10" 
       style="width:500px" 
       multiple 
       ui-select2="params.options.citizenshipOptions"   
       ng-model="cvLang.content.citizenship"
       ng-repeat="a in [1]"
 />
```

**ng-repeat="a in [1]" is a magical thing!!!** It is not clear for me a logic of a context, but this is working. May be this can help?